# Change 'Appendices' label in table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, appendices

I need to change an element of the table of contents.
In particular all appendices titles are displayed after the word 'Appendices':

```
    Appendices
    APPENDIX A
    APPENDIX B
```

I would like to change the word 'Appendices' to something else:

```
    Something else
    APPENDIX A
    APPENDIX B
```

How can I do this? Thanks!

---

Some code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,8pt]{book}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\renewcommand{\appendixname}{Appendice}
\renewcommand{\appendixpagename}{Appendici}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Without telling us anything about how you are producing your document, it's very difficult to tell. Can you edit your question to show us a tiny compilable document that produces the output in the first part, and then we can probably show you how to change it to the second part.

Comment: @AlanMunn Edited

Comment: This is helpful, but it's a code fragment, not a compilable document that people can play with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you should do it. Note that there is no `8pt` size option for the `book` class.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{book} % there is no 8pt size option for the book class
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\addto\extrasitalian{%
\renewcommand{\appendixname}{Appendice}
\renewcommand{\appendixpagename}{Appendici}
\renewcommand{\appendixtocname}{Appendici}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{A chapter}
\begin{appendices}
\chapter{First appendix}
\chapter{Second appendix}
\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of TOC]